# Graph of a Sequence of Functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, continuity, graphing-functions

So, I looked up this question from G.H. Hardy's *A Course of Pure Mathematics* and found one examination question from the Cambridge Mathematical Tripos and it has baffled me ever since. I am supposed to sketch

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{x^{2n}\sin{(\pi x/2)}+x^2}{x^{2n}+1}$

I have found out that this approaches $\sin(\pi x/2)$ (not sure whether am I right or not) and the graphs look like the image attached below but I am told that there is one discontinuity. So, how do I sketch it correctly?

[The possible graphs of the sequence of function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0r8f.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that
$$f_n(x):=\dfrac{x^{2n}\sin{(\pi x/2)}+x^2}{x^{2n}+1}=\sin(\pi x/2)+\dfrac{x^2-\sin{(\pi x/2)}}{x^{2n}+1}.$$
Moreover,
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}x^{2n}=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
        0 & \text{if $|x|<1$, } \\
        1 & \text{if $|x|=1$, } \\
        +\infty & \text{if $|x|>1$, }
        \end{array}\right.
\quad\Rightarrow\quad
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{x^{2n}+1}=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
        1 & \text{if $|x|<1$, } \\
        1/2 & \text{if $|x|=1$, } \\
        0 & \text{if $|x|>1$. }
        \end{array}\right.
$$
Therefore 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
        \sin(\pi x/2) & \text{if $|x|>1$, } \\
        1 & \text{if $x=1$, } \\
        0 & \text{if $x=-1$, } \\
        x^2 & \text{if $|x|<1$, }
        \end{array}\right.
.$$

Comment: Thanks dude. I've figured out

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
\lim \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x^{2n}\sin(\pi x/2)+x^2}{x^{2n}+1} &= \lim \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sin(\pi x/2)+x^{2-2n}}{1+x^{-2n}}\\
&=\lim \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sin(\pi x/2)+0}{1+0}
\end{align*}